# iOS App Maximise Disappears

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode-storyboard

I have developed an iOS app and everything is working as expected apart from the "maximise" icon in the detail view when it is turned sideways has disappeared.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this feature and suspect I have either not initialized something in the code or missed a setting on the story board.

Using objective C.

Comment: Are you talking about the `displayModeButtonItem` on `UISplitViewController`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. At least I know what it is called now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Knowing what it was called helps a lot :-)

Issue was the below code missing from viewDidLoad in the DetailViewController

UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;